# angular5 lazy load multiple component

Tags: angular, angular5

I have `HeaderComponent`,`FootComponent` and Customer Components.I had create `CustomerModule` and `CustomerRoutingModule`

CustomerModule

```
declarations: [CustomerComponent]
```

CustomerRoutingModule

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustbasicdetailsComponent
  }
];
```

App.routing

```
{ 
  path: 'custbasicdetails' ,
  loadChildren: 'app/customer/customer.module#CustomerModule' 
},
```

But i am getting error

```
  'header' is not a known element:
     1. If 'header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

EDITED :

`HeaderComponent`,`FooterComponent` in app.module.ts

Comment: Do you import (defined in declarations) the header-component in your modules? It must be imported in all modules where you want to use it.

Comment: Yes..HeaderComponent,FooterComponent in app.module.ts

Comment: But are you using those compoents in your CustomerModule aswell? Then you'd have to import them there aswell.

Comment: Its not work.I you get  Error: Type HeaderComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and CustomerModule! Please consider moving HeaderComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and CustomerModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HeaderComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and CustomerModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to import your HeaderComponent and FootComponent in your app.module.ts only and put those 2 nested components in app.component.html. and you don't have to import your CustomerModule inside app module because it's a lazyloaded module.
your app.module.ts will be like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent,  FootComponent ]
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and your app.component.html will be :

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer><app-footer>
```

and app.routes will be :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/custbasicdetails', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'custbasicdetails' , loadChildren: 'app/customer/customer.module#CustomerModule' 
}
]
```

customer.routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: 'CustbasicdetailsComponent ', pathMatch: 'full' }
}
]
```

Comment: Thanks.But i can't get any customer.module.bundle.js file

Comment: for loadChildren try the relative path to you app.module , loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule

Comment: No error bro.. I have added const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustbasicdetailsComponent
  }
]; in CustomerRoutingModule

Comment: i didn't any chunk files for customer

Comment: try this, [ { path: '', component: CustbasicdetailsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' } ]

Comment: where bro. app.module or CustomerRoutingModule ?

Comment: CustomerRoutingModule

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167807/discussion-between-vikram-r-and-fateh-mohamed).

Answer (score 1):

Export Header, Footer and Customer components in their respective `@NgModules`.

Like this.

in customer.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [CustomerComponent],
  exports: [CustomerComponent],
})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, CustomerModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent]
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

Do the same for header and footer.

You declare component only once in a single `@NgModule's` declarations array. If you want to use this component in another `@NgModule` you must:

1. export the component by placing it in `@NgModule's` `exports` array.
2. import the  `@NgModule` declaring the component into the `@NgModule`, that wants to use it, by placing it in that `@NgModule` `imports` array.

Read more about [feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules)

Comment: Can you explain briefly please. If you give Full Example i will appreciate

Comment: Based on you comment above you need to remove `HeaderComponent` either from `AppModule` or `CustomerModule`. It must be a part of only a single `@NgModule`. You declare components only once in one `@NgModule`.

Comment: Thanks.But i can't get any customer.module.bundle.js file